# setUpperBound of pictured chart

Tags: java, charts, javafx, axis, upperbound

Can I change the maximum value of Axis if LineChart is drawn already?
I know about `setUpperBound()` method, but I see that it works well when it is used with initialization of chart. But I want to change upper and lower bounds of an existed chart (there is no result).

Comment: After you've changed the upperbounds, are you refreshing the image?

Comment: It is refreshed automatically after any change in chart. 
The problem was: 
yAxis.setAutoRanging(true);
It must be false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in auto ranging. 
Desicion:

```
 yAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
```